# Square of a triple sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, random-variables

Consider the square of a triple sum:
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^d  \sum_{j=1}^d  \sum_{k=1}^d x_i y_j z_k \right) \left( \sum_{i'=1}^d \sum_{j'=1}^d \sum_{k'=1}^d  x_{i'} y_{j'} z_{k'} \right),
\end{equation}
where $x_i, y_j, z_k$ are mutually independent random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[x_i] = \mathbb{E}[y_j] = \mathbb{E}[z_k] = a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{E}[x_i^2] = \mathbb{E}[y_j^2] = \mathbb{E}[z_k^2] = b \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have a solution but I'm interested in solving this for the more general case where we have an arbitrary number of sums (say $l>3$), i.e.
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{i_1=1}^d  \sum_{i_2=1}^d  \dots \sum_{i_l=1}^d x^{(1)}_{i_1} x^{(2)}_{i_2} \dots x^{(l)}_{i_l} \right)^2.
\end{equation}

Here is my solution for the case where we have three sums.
First, one can rewrite the previous equation as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{i'=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^d \sum_{j'=1}^d \sum_{k=1}^d \sum_{k'=1}^d \left( x_i x_{i'} y_j y_{j'} z_k z_{k'} \right)
\end{equation}

Then one can split each pairs of sums $\sum_i \sum_{i'} (\cdot) = \sum_i + \sum_{i \neq i'}$. This gives rise to $2^3$ cases to consider, which we summarize in the table below.

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
i = i' & j = j' & k = k' & \# 0's & \# 1's & \# summands & value \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & d^3(d-1)^3 & a^6 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & d^3(d-1)^2 & a^4 b \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & d^3(d-1)^2 & a^4 b \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & d^3(d-1) & a^2 b^2 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & d^3(d-1)^2 & a^4 b \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & d^3(d-1) & a^2 b^2 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & d^3(d-1) & a^4 b \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & d^3 & b^3 \\ \hline
\end{array}

For each $0$ in a row, the number of corresponding summands is $d(d-1)$ while for each $1$, we have a total of $d$ terms. For instance, for the combination $000$, we get $(d(d-1))^3$.

We obtain the desired solution by summing the product of the last two columns.

I would like to know if there is a way to compute the final solution in a closed form in such a way that it can be generalized to $l>3$ sums.